# C# add custom HTTP header

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

My client's web service use some custom HTTP headers like:

```
:path=api/xxxx
:authority=apikey
```

When i tried add these headers to a HttpRequestMessage, throw a exception mean these headers are not correct, and TryAddWithoutValidation does not work too. Is there any other way to add custom HTTP header?

[image]

Comment: which client are you using?

Comment: I use HttpClient to send a HttpRequestMessage

Comment: Are you sure you have the format correct?  The standard format would be `path:api/xxxx` and `authority:apikey` which would give you a call of `TryAddWithoutValidation("path", "api/xxxx")`  I don't think I have ever seen headers with that format.

Comment: I upload a picture to show you the request headers via chrome